# Show all results of xml display in the fragment with scrollbar

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

New to android, I want to render all the book results in my fragment below. But only first book is appearing. Not sure how to have all books in same picture and details format in a sequence?

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/ScrollView01"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    android:scrollbars="none" >

    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.androidatc.customviewindrawer.SearchBookFrag"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/enter_keyword"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="33dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Enter Keyword"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/book_keyword"
        android:text=""
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/book_title"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/book_title"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/enter_keyword"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/search_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="@string/search"
        android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="144dp"
        android:layout_height="190dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:src="@android:color/black" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_title"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Title" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_publisher"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/book_title"
        android:layout_weight="0.05"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Publisher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_creator"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/book_publisher"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Creator" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/book_availability"
        android:layout_width="190dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/book_creator"
        android:layout_weight="0.03"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="Availablity" />


</RelativeLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Part of java class - where I am parsing xml results is as below, not sure how to retrieve all results?

```
 public void readDetails(String response) {
        DocumentBuilder builder = null;

    try {
        builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        InputSource src = new InputSource();

        src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(response));

//        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "src:" + "\n"
//                + src, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Document doc = builder.parse(src);

        NodeList nodes1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("dc:title");


        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Total Number of Books Found:"
                + nodes1.getLength(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //String available = doc.getElementsByTagName("zs:numberOfRecords").item(0).getTextContent();
        String title = doc.getElementsByTagName("dc:title").item(0).getTextContent();
        String creator1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("dc:creator").item(0).getTextContent();
        String creator2 = doc.getElementsByTagName("dc:creator").item(1).getTextContent();
        String publisher = doc.getElementsByTagName("dc:publisher").item(0).getTextContent();
        String description = doc.getElementsByTagName("dc:description").item(0).getTextContent();

        NodeList list = doc.getElementsByTagName("dc:duedate");


        src.setCharacterStream(new StringReader(response));



        NodeList nodes = doc.getElementsByTagName("dc:duedate");


        int cnt=0;
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            if(nodes.item(i).getTextContent().trim().isEmpty()){
                cnt++;
            }

        }
        Log.e("TAGLOG", "" + cnt);



        TitleTxt.setText("Title: " + title);

        PublisherTxt.setText("Publisher: " + publisher);
        CreatorTxt.setText("Creator: " + creator1 + "," + creator2);

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "No Book Found", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } finally {

    }
```

Here XML may return any number of results (0 to many). Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put scroll view for id="@+id/container". So remove Relative Layout and replace it with scroll view

Comment: I want multiple results to appear in different rows. display of 1st book is working perfectly. I donno how to show book 2 to more books (which are the result of xml parsing) in the same fragment with scroll bar.above code is working fine, just that I want to show all the results.

Comment: I found this tutorial, I hope this is what you are looking for, skip to 10:32 to see the what he did: [tutoria](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DfW9G6qTvcc)

Comment: ok, let me check the recyclerview..had no idea on how to do it. Many thanks.